# C# Output text to file on a new line

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have some code which outputs data from the FileSystemWatcher class, although each times to outputs a line to test.txt, it overwrites the previous entry, is there a way to stop this happening?

Code in question:

```
static void FileWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{

    using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test3.txt"))
    {
        var data = true;
        fileWriter.Write("C:\\" + e.Name + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Full Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace FileWatcherr
{
class Program
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dirPath = "C:\\";
        FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(dirPath); 
        fileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;  
        fileWatcher.Filter = "*.exe";    
        // fileWatcher.Filter = "C:\\$Recycle.Bin";   
        //  fileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Changed);   
        fileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Created);    
        //  fileWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Deleted);  
        //  fileWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(FileWatcher_Renamed);    
        fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;      

        // updated code


        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }



        static void FileWatcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.OldName + " was renamed to " + e.Name);
        }

        static void FileWatcher_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)

        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Name + " was deleted");
        }

        static void FileWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {

            using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test3.txt"))
            {
                var data = true;
                fileWriter.Write("C:\\" + e.Name + Environment.NewLine);
            }

        }

        static void FileWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Name + "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As lots of people have suggested the same thing, you can assume that it is correct. Something else is a problem for you, so please add info of your new problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your code to be the below. The second parameter to the `StreamWriter` is if we should append or overwrite. Set to true to append and false to overwrite (default, thus your problem)

```
   using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test3.txt", true))
    {
        var data = true;
        fileWriter.WriteLine(Path.Combine("C:\\", e.Name));
    }
```

More info about this constructor can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx

Comment: @Michael what is the problem? I found a syntax error I fixed, try the current code

Answer (score 0):

Consider opening file to append:

```
    using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test3.txt", true))
    {
        var data = true;
        fileWriter.WriteLine("C:\\" + e.Name);
    }
```

Note that it is better to use `WriteLine` method.

Comment: Use string.format or with Concat function instead of concatenating strings your way

Comment: @dario Even though it is correct that you should not just add together strings, combining paths is usually recommended to be done with Path.Combine

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test3.txt", true))
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
new StreamWriter("test3.txt")
```

by

```
new StreamWriter("test3.txt", true)
```

This will make the stream append to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The StreamWriter class has an overload constructor that takes a second bool parameter which specifies if you want to append to an existing file. [More information here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx)